# Submit not working in Chrome on an HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

We have a small application that is hosted on Lotus notes which is working on all browsers except Chrome.

### The HTML is

```
<form method="post" action="/Start?OpenForm&amp;Seq=1&amp;erc=0" name="_Begin">


<input name="textfield" value="" class="line" size="49">
<!-- Submit Button-->
<a onclick="submit() return false;" href=""><img src="page.nsf/Beg_r5_c4.jpg?OpenImageResource" width="145" height="23" id="Beg_r5_c4" border="0"></a>
```

### The JS is

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
document._domino_target = "_self";
function _doClick(v, o, t, h) {
  var form = document._Begin;
  if (form.onsubmit) {
     var retVal = form.onsubmit();
     if (typeof retVal == "boolean" && retVal == false)
       return false;
  }
  var target = document._domino_target;
  if (o.href != null) {
    if (o.target != null)
       target = o.target;
  } else {
    if (t != null)
      target = t;
  }
  form.target = target;
  form.__Click.value = v;
  if (h != null)
    form.action += h;
  form.submit();
  return false;
}
// -->
</script>
```

Any idea why it's not working in Chrome?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call `_doClick`? Where is `submit()` function defined? I don't see how this could submit the form with the code provided.

Comment: That's the problem that this is hosted on Lotus Notes and this page doesn't include any JS files. All the JS it has is pasted above. I am thus unable to understand where this `_doClick_` is being called and where `submit()` is defined.

Comment: Do you see any error in the JS console?